# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/j_spring_security_login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, handler

I added this login link to my Spring app:

```
<a href="<spring:url value="/j_spring_security_login" htmlEscape="true" />">
Sign In
</a>
```

My assumption was that because this is a built-in tag for accessing the login page, Spring would know how to associate this with an appropriate handler without me having to specify it explicitly.

However, it generates the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI 
[/app/j_spring_security_login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

What's the appropriate way to define the handler for this URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/j_spring_security_login` is a special Spring Security's url, so it's handled by the Spring Security filter and you don't need to define any other handler for it. Just check that you have a properly configured and mapped Spring Security filter, as described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a servlet named "dispatcher" that maps to `DispatcherServlet` in your web.xml?  If not, do add it in.

If that's not the case, check out [this entry](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-25627.html) at the Spring forum.  You aren't the first person with this problem.

Comment: Yes, I have a servlet mapping for dispatcher in web.xml.